# Creating an associative array from an array, based on the array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a unique issue that I have never heard of this being possible to do before:

So essentially I have a function that takes in a an array of arguments such as:

```
function someFunction(array $arguments){}
```

and gives me an array back as such:

```
array('option1', 'option2', 'options3', ...);
```

I then need to take that array and loop through it creating an associative array such as:

```
array('option1' => call_come_method('option1'), .... );
```

heres the kicker, you will never know how many arguments a user passes into the function, yet each one needs to created into a key=>value arrangement as seen above.

Now i did some research and I was told the [$argv command in php](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php), how ever where I am stumped is how to implement it in this case.

So if any one can give me any pointers I would be appreciative.

Comment: Which function don't you know how many arguments will be passed into?

Comment: `$argv` doesn't seem relevant here. It is usually used when you use a command line utility to run the script.

Comment: "you will never know how many arguments a user passes into the function"... `count($arguments)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a lot easier than you think.  First use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) to switch the array's keys and values.

```
$newArray = array_flip($arguments);
```

Then loop though it and call the method:

```
foreach($newArray as $key=>&$val){
    $val = call_come_method($key);
}
```

The `&`, makes it a reference, so the array value is updated.

DEMO: http://codepad.org/giL1KPA3

**UPDATE**: You don't even need `array_flip`, you just need a for loop.

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($arguments as $val){
    $newArray[$val] = call_come_method($val);
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.org/AQ1gWrou

Answer (score 1):

> you will never know how many arguments a user passes into the function

FYI, you get to know it with [func_get_args()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php).

This way you don't need to provide your function with an `$arguments` parameter, but you just leave it empty.